# Including precompiled ember handlebar templates

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I've successfully precompiled handlebars into one file using grunt-ember-templates, however, when including source in html file:

```
<script src="templates/app/compiledTemplates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It says this:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///Users/jaime/voyant-svn/voyant-blocks/dev/blocks-web/src/main/webapp/templates/app/compiledTemplates.devjs".
```

What is the proper way of including precompiled handlebar templates?

Comment: Are you sure you want to compile your templates into the templates directory? I generally put my assembled code into a "dist" folder, so that it won't mess with any other actual source code I might have in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combine the compiled templates with my other scripts (jQuery/ember/ember-data/my app code) using grunt. Then in my index.html I simply include the single js script (helps cut down on the number of http requests also).

I'm currently using grunt for this, a simple "build" step might look something like the below. To use this you would need to install nodejs. Next you would npm install the following

```
grunt
grunt-cli
grunt-ember-template-compiler
grunt-contrib-concat
```

Once you have these installed you can run the build below from your root if you put the js into a file called "Gruntfile.js" -then simply execute "grunt" and it will output a deps.min.js (w/ your script and templates combined)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-template-compiler');

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      dist: {
          src: [
            'website/static/website/script/vendor/handlebars-v1.2.1.js',
            'website/static/website/script/vendor/ember.min.js',
            'website/static/website/script/my-app.js’,
            'website/static/website/script/dist/tmpl.min.js'],
          dest: 'website/static/website/script/dist/deps.min.js'
      }
    },
    emberhandlebars: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                templateName: function(sourceFile) {
                    var newSource = sourceFile.replace('website/static/website/script/app/templates/', '');
                    return newSource.replace('.handlebars', '');
                }
            },
            files: ['website/static/website/script/app/templates/**/*.handlebars'],
            dest: 'website/static/website/script/dist/tmpl.min.js'
        }
    }
  });

  grunt.task.registerTask('default', ['emberhandlebars', 'concat:dist']);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in my app:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="dist/templates.js"></script>
```

You can see the whole index.html file here:

https://github.com/joachimhs/WarmCroc-Ember/blob/master/index.html

In, fact, I just wrote this code today during a live-coding presentation on Ember.js. The talk is recorded as a screencast, and is available from http://emberjstraining.com

This talks should give you the pointers you need to get everything set up properly :)

Comment: I'll definitely watch the talk; it seems useful info.

Comment: I seem to be compiling the templates very similarly to you. Except the only difference is that my template files contain script tags (<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="employment">) in the files. I suppose I need to remove these for the precompiling to work properly? If so, how can I add the info I need (id, data-template-name,etc) into those templates if I cannot use tags?

Comment: You should have your templates inside a separate template directory. The subdirectory and the name of the template file will tell grunt-ember-tempaltes the id of the template, and will compile all of your templates into a single JavaScript file. There should be no script tags inside this file at all, and neither inside any of you .hbs files. This gist gives an example of the output from the precompilation: https://gist.github.com/joachimhs/8466570 Have a look at the .hbs files from here: https://github.com/joachimhs/WarmCroc-Ember/tree/master/templates